# Limit write access to JSON file on AWS S3 server

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am developing an app that is able to read from JSON file located on AWS S3 servers in a bucket with read and write permissions. App also allows to edit some of the values in that JSON file.

**Problem**

Problem is that everyone with the JSON file URL can then alter the included data. I only want the file to be modified from this app.

**JSON file**

```
{
  "females": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First Name",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_1": 123,
          "action_2": 456,
          "action_3": 789
        }
      ]
    }, ...    
}
```

Users are able to modify values located withing actions array.

Any recommendations on how to limit write access of the JSON file only to this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudfront will not help here.

Solution is

- authenticate your application's users (Amazon Cognito will help you) OR use Amazon Cognito with Anonymous User.
- Give your Amazon Cognito role the permission to read and write on your S3 bucket
- remove access policies from S3 (to make the bucket private)

That way, only application users will be able to read and write the files.

Comment: This definitely looks like the way to do it. Although it looks complicated it's worth a try. Thank you.

Comment: I got it to work! I followed the guide on this website: https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the following:
[Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

You can use CloudFront to mask and/or create a layer between your content (in S3) and the user/s. This allows for better control over the access management rather than storing and giving out the actual links to S3 URLS.